# How do you use .htaccess to redirect multiple subdirectories to root directory?

Tags: apache-http-server, website, url, rewrite, forum

I have a website. The website's url is web.pixelblock.us.to. Unfortunately, the forum software writes the urls as http://web.pixelblock.us.to/home/pbnx10ho/public_html/$1. I want .htaccess to redirect http://web.pixelblock.us.to/home/pbnx10ho/public_html/$1 to http://web.pixelblock.us.to/$1.
Any help at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Open your directory of web.pixelblock.us.to then open .htaccess file it would be hidden so turn on show hidden filed then search the htaccess file rewrite engine on or something like rewrite.
Find your home url and check its redirection. You can fix it manually or try any htaccess builder for that.
Google for it.